# Including other one jbuilder template in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

Consider the following `show.json.jbuilder` template:

```
json.user do |json|
    json.extract! @user, :id, :username, :email, :created_at, :avatar
end

json.policies do |json|
    json.array!(@policies) do |policy|
        json.extract! policy, :id, :title, :cached_votes_score
    end
end

json.liked do |json|
    json.array!(@liked) do |policy|
        json.extract! policy, :id, :title, :cached_votes_score
    end
end

json.disliked do |json|
    json.array!(@disliked) do |policy|
        json.extract! policy, :id, :title, :cached_votes_score
    end
end
```

Would it be possible to split those up into four different templates, and then just include them in the `show` template? Something like:

```
include template_user
include template_policies
include template_liked
include template_disliked
```

If this is not possible, what alternatives exist for creating more modular jbuilder code? I find my jbuilder code very un-DRY.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Is possible. Split your files like:

_user.json.jbuilder

`json.user do |json|
    json.extract! @user, :id, :username, :email, :created_at, :avatar
end`

_policies.json.jbuilder

`json.policies do |json|
    json.array!(@policies) do |policy|
        json.extract! policy, :id, :title, :cached_votes_score
    end
end`

_liked.json.jbuilder

`json.liked do |json|
    json.array!(@liked) do |policy|
        json.extract! policy, :id, :title, :cached_votes_score
    end
end`

_disliked.json.jbuilder

`json.disliked do |json|
    json.array!(@disliked) do |policy|
        json.extract! policy, :id, :title, :cached_votes_score
    end
end`

and then you can simply join them with:

show.json.jbuilder

`json.partial! 'user'
json.partial! 'policies'
json.partial! 'liked'
json.partial! 'disliked'`

But I would suggest to improve them a little bit and write them using local variables and so:

_user.json.jbuilder

`json.user do |json|
    json.extract! user, :id, :username, :email, :created_at, :avatar
end`

and you include it passing the user as an argument:

`json.partial! 'user', user: @user`

Comment: This is great, and thanks for the note on local variables! One follow-up question: is it possible to include a partial that does not have a name beginning with an underscore?

Comment: No. The partials have an underscore as first character, otherwise are views.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to be able to use a view as a view in certain cases, or as a partial in others. I realize I can do this by simply calling `render template: ...` in my controller method on the partial, but I was hoping to be able to avoid that.

Comment: You don't want to do that. Would be conceptually and architecturally wrong. Just make a view which renders one single partial and reuse the partial